# jQuery datepicker only working on first .datepicker element

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to have the jQuery datepicker work on multiple elements on the page. I'm using jQuery 1.11.3 and jQuery-UI 1.12.1

I've given each element a class of .mydatepicker:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".mydatepicker").datepicker();
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery + jQuery ui & Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS 1.5.8 -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<!-- Firebase not working in snippet -->
<!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-data-firebase/2.1.1/js-data-firebase.min.js"></script>-->

<!-- AngularFire -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angularFire/2.1.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap UI -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input class="form-control mydatepicker" aria-label="Date" placeholder="01/01/2000" type="text" ng-model="blah.due">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input date-directive class="form-control mydatepicker" aria-label="Date" type="text" ng-model="blah.due" ng-change="blahs.$save(blah)">       
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It only works on 1 though...

Comment: It works on all 3 in the snippet

Comment: Yeah I know there must be something else in my code that's stopping it. Might try adding the lot here as a test and see if it runs.

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Do you have any callback functions in the datepicker options? Make sure they use `$(this)` to access the current datepicker, not `$(".datepicker")`

Comment: No I don't have any.

Comment: Maybe you've loaded some other library that has a datepicker, and it's replacing the jQuery UI datepicker.

Comment: I've pasted all the other js files I've loaded up there in the snippet and it appears to work with them

Comment: None of those other JS files exist here on SO, so those links are all failing in the snippet.

Comment: I just made a jsfiddle with all the html, javascript and external js resources and the datepickers work in both. It kind of suggests to me that the problem has to be with angular... Maybe one of the directives? I'm at a loss

Comment: Any output from console when the page loads or when you fire the first datepicker? There may be an error generated during the first event that is causing future events to fail.

Comment: No I didn't see any errors at all